# Wirless ap-hotspot ubuntu 13.10

Tags: network-manager, hot-spot

I have Ubuntu 13.10 and I created a wireless hot spot using the network setting option and also tried to setup using AP-hotspot.

The problem is the one setup using network setting is not showing in my phone (Android 4.0) and when I start **AP-hotspot** it says already a process is running and if I stop and try to start again it says another process already running again.

Comment: Could you tell us step by step what you did?

Comment: Does this work for you http://askubuntu.com/a/71976/59090

Comment: Your question also maybe a duplicate of the above question. There is a known issue when trying to connect and Android phone to a ad-hoc network.

Answer (score 7):

> when I start AP-hot spot it says already a process is running and if I stop and try to start again it says another process already running again

Your command prompt should look like this,

```
$ sudo ap-hotspot start
Another process is already running
$ sudo ap-hotspot stop
Wireless Hotspot is not active
```

In this case whatever command you try, won't work. It would display the same error like  above.

**For this you have to remove `hotspot.pid` file present inside `/tmp` directory. So that only it would  work.**

```
sudo rm /tmp/hotspot.pid
```

And then try to start ap-hotspot by running,

```
sudo ap-hotspot start
```

To stop,

```
sudo ap-hotspot stop
```

To configure,

```
sudo ap-hotspot configure
```

Answer (score 0):

Last time I needed to share the internet connection on a laptop with an Android mobile phone, I encountered similar issues: your Android may or may not recognize an Ad-Hoc network.

In the end I managed to create a hotspot Access Point using [wifi-hostapd-ap](http://code.google.com/p/wifi-hostapd-ap/), a GUI to create WiFi access point based on Hostapd. I had to disable DNS in NetworkManager to [avoid wifi-hostapd-ap crashing](http://code.google.com/p/wifi-hostapd-ap/issues/detail?id=8), though.

See also:

- [How to setup an Access Point mode Wi-Fi Hotspot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-access-point-mode)
- [Is there a GUI app to setup and toggle hostapd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191889/is-there-a-gui-app-to-setup-and-toggle-hostapd)

Answer (score 0):

Install `iw` & execute following:

```
iw list
```

Look for supported interface section

```
Supported interface modes:
     * IBSS
     * managed
     * AP
     * AP/VLAN
     * monitor
```

If you have `AP` you're good.

Then follow [this](http://dashohoxha.blogspot.in/2013/06/how-to-setup-wifi-access-point-on-ubuntu.html) guide.

I have been through the pains of setting up `Hotspot` on an unsupported card.

Hope this helps.